# What happens when 4 batteries are in series, but with wrong polarity?

Tags: batteries, series

I remember that, as a child, we had an electronic game that didn't have a proper ON/OFF button. So someone older in my family used this trick "to power it off": they flipped one of 1.5V AA battery, i.e. instead of:

```
- BATTERY1 + | - BATTERY2 + | - BATTERY3 + | - BATTERY4 +      (normal)
```

we had

```
- BATTERY1 + | - BATTERY2 + | + BATTERY3 - | - BATTERY4 +      ("powered off")
```

If I remeber well, it worked, and it didn't drain the batteries faster, it didn't damage the electronic device.

Questions:

- What happens to the batteries if we do that?
- The electronic device will probably receive 1.5 + 1.5 - 1.5 + 1.5 ~ 3V (confirmed with a test I just did with a multimeter), but can the batteries be damaged (heat?) and/or the device?

---

PS: decades later, now my son has great talkie/walkies, but it has the drawback of draining 1 mA even when powered off. After weeks, the batteries are empty even if it was not used. I was thinking about using the same "trick", that's why I wanted to be sure of the consequences for the batteries and the device.

Comment: Can you draw this as a schematic? Then you can also trivially derive the voltages that your device sees. I don't really understand what the question here is – your other questions clearly indicate you know how "voltage" works, so this is really just an exercise in writing down four numbers with different signs? Can you explain what you do not understand?

Comment: @Basj I expect you received a down vote from someone because your question doesn't show any research effort. Reversing one battery from the four cancels a forward connected battery and, instead of 4x 1.5 volts (6 volts) you get 3 volts. Also, you might find that using lithium batteries you are forcing one to become charged (the reverse one) due to there still being current flow into the load albeit at only 50% of the normal voltage across the load. You need to reverse 50% of the batteries to get 0 volts out.

Comment: Although you expected and measured that, you didn't put that in the question, but instead asked for the voltage. So, edit your question to specify what you've done, and what you *actually* wonder about :)

Comment: Nobody likes to have a set of lithium cells in a state of relative imbalance when returned to their normal position. Reverse 50% of the cells to be more assured that the target system receives 0 volts.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did a mistake in my previous comments, indeed I see ~ 3V (I just re-did a test with a multimeter).

Comment: @Andyaka I think your last comment gives the answer (if you want to post one); what would be the worst that can happen with 3 batt. in forward, and 1 in reverse (thus ~ 3V)? Can this overheat the reverse battery?

Comment: The backwards battery will probably start to leak.  Don't do this.  Just remove the batteries when not in use

Comment: What do you mean by to leak @KyleB? Which exact chemical or electrical effect happens?

Comment: The reversed battery gets charged by the other cells.   Eventually the internal pressure gets too high and the seals open up, allowing the chemicals inside to escape.

Comment: @KyleB This is the information I was looking for, thanks. I think this is the answer if you want to post it.

Comment: Haha  Not worried about credit for an answer   ;)     I would like to add, though, this is enough of a 'real' problem that toys age graded below 5 or so, that use 3 or more batteries, have to have their battery boxes designed to prevent a reverse connected cell from making a contact.

Comment: @KyleB Oh this is good to know. Is there a "norm" about this or EU / US specifications that require this specific thing for a toy to be allowed to be distributed in the market? If you have a source about this, I'd be interested to read (just out of curiosity!)

Comment: Ok ... I can quote the EU requirement, but not today (not at work).  The EU regulations are not available as a download, you have to pay to get them so I can't give you a link.   It will be in the EU62115  regulation 'Electric Toy Safety Standards'

Comment: Thanks for this info, happy to learn about this @KyleB! (Off-topic remark: sad that a EU regulation law/specification, that anyone who builds toys has to follow, is not public!)

Comment: I guess removing the batteries is not an option because they get lost.  But put in a piece of cardboard to break the circuit and avoid the whole problem. I guess there's enough room to store the piece in the battery box when the device is in use.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in the comments, you already know what happens: the device sees 0 volts, and likely nothing bad will *likely* happen. However, this assumes that the device uses the batteries wired in series, as such:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTryyj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'd wager this is likely the case in all situations. However, it's certainly possible, however unlikely, that the device has the batteries wired in parallel instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvUXEc.png)</sup>

In this case, there's the obvious dangers that result from shorting a battery . Depending on the battery type and the number of batteries, this could result in danger ranging anywhere from reasonably benign to quite Exciting™.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Important note: your first schematic is a situation in which 2 batteries are reversed from normal wiring. If only 1 is reversed, it's ~3V.

Comment: @Shamtam, no I think basj is right. 1.5+1.5+1.5-1.5 = 3

Comment: Duh. Early morning stupidity on my part 

Answer (score 0):

If half the batteries are installed backward, and all the batteries have exactly the same voltage, you have 0 voltage out, and no current will flow.

What happens if one of the batteries is more discharged than the others will depend upon what type of batteries they are, and what the circuit they are in.

Many circuits are will conduct some electricity, even when the voltage applied to them is below their normal operating voltage. If that is the case, some (perhaps very small) current will flow if the batteries do not have exactly idential voltage.

If current does flow, what happens to the batteries depends upon whether they are re-chargable or not.

If the batteries are rechargable, then the flow of current will drain the batteries with higher voltage, and charge the batteries with lower voltage, bringing them closer together, until ultimately they have the same voltage, and the current stops flowing.

If the batteries are not rechargable, then the flow of current will drain the batteries with higher voltage, and possibly damage the batteries with lower voltage. I say possibly, because the current may or may not be quite small, depending upon circumstances.

If 3 of the batteries, are installed with correct polarity, and the 4th is reversed, and all the batteries have approximately the same charge (exactness doesn't matter in this case), and if the circuit they are connected to draws power even when a lower voltage is applied to it than it's normal operating voltage, then current will flow through the batteries.

If current flows, over time this will probably damage the reversed battery, even if it is rechargeable. The reversed battery, even if rechargeable, cannot be charged to the point that it's voltage exactly counter-acts that of the 3 other batteries. Thus, the battery will overcharge if it is rechargable, and receive significant current in the wrong direction if it is not rechargeable.

Damage will not occur, however, if the circuit does NOT draw significant current unless the voltage applied is above some threshold. Fortunately, many electronic circuits are like that. (Incandescent flash-lights, if anyone still uses them, are not).

Comment: Small correction: I redid the test and I get a 3 V voltage indeed (1.5+1.5-1.5+1.5), so you might want to edit the answer.

Comment: Added case where 3 batteries are of correct polarity, and one is reversed

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should theoretically happen if they are equal voltages.

However.....If we consider manufacturing tolerances and variations in internal resistances of cells, we can get some discharging across the cells.This ends up as heat until the voltage normalizes to zero.